# How can I set current date (Today's date) same as selected date in Material Date Picker Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calendar, material-design

How can I set current date (Today's date) to my local date. My timezone is GMT+07:00. I can just set only setSelection() date but can't set current date.
(Sorry for my any grammatical mistake and thank you in advance)
[Calendar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj6yR.png)

```
  val c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+07:00"))
        val gmtTime: Long = c.getTime().getTime()
        c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok"));
        val timezoneThailand: Long = gmtTime + TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok").rawOffset
        c.setTimeInMillis(timezoneThailand)
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

//        view.chooseDateButton.text = c.toString()
        val calendarConstraintBuilder = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
        calendarConstraintBuilder.setStart(1640995200000)
        calendarConstraintBuilder.setEnd(1646092800000)
        calendarConstraintBuilder.setValidator(DateValidatorPointBackward.now());

        val materialDateBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
        materialDateBuilder.setTitleText("SELECT DATE TO SHOW IMAGES");

        materialDateBuilder.setSelection(c.timeInMillis)

//        materialDateBuilder.setTheme(R.style.DefaultDatePickerTheme)

        materialDateBuilder.setCalendarConstraints(calendarConstraintBuilder.build())
        val materialDatePicker : MaterialDatePicker<*> = materialDateBuilder.build()
```

Comment: It uses the current date as the initial selection by default, so you don't have to call `setSelection()` at all. You can also get the current date as a Long to pass to `setSelection` by using `MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds()`

Comment: I mean the initial selection not match with my real local date and the initial current date not match as well.

Comment: Is it off by one day? Are you sure your device is set to the correct date? It uses UTC so your timeline should be irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, It off by one day. I'm so confused my device setting absolutely correct. [link](https://sv1.picz.in.th/images/2022/02/03/ne34zb.png)

Comment: My current code (above code) it's correct date only selected date (green circle) but I want to set new black hollow circle date.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I don’t think you can change the black circled date. It is on whatever the device’s current date is.

Comment: Nevermind Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think you don't need to worry about timezone at all. It's all handled automatically. Remove all code regarding to your Calendar `c` and just do the selection with

```
materialDateBuilder.setSelection(Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis)
```

Comment: [This is the result image](https://sv1.picz.in.th/images/2022/02/03/nekaLE.png) I have tried that code. Thank you but It's not match with my local date . I just want to set a new current date.

Comment: It definitely matche when I use `materialDateBuilder.setSelection(c.timeInMillis)`  for selected date (green circle) but I can't set current date(black hollow circle).  [IMAGE LINK](https://sv1.picz.in.th/images/2022/02/03/ne34zb.png)

Comment: @zEPHOP ah i misunderstood. I thought the selected date was wrong for you. Sorry i misread. Current date is just current date. You can't change that. It takes your device's date probably. You can't change that programmatically

Comment: Thanks for your helpful information